# Glassdoor data scraping using selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

While going through jobs listings in GlassDoor website, a signup message will popup and I'm trying to close the popup message by clicking on the " X " button. I have mentioned the class name correctly but still couldn't close the popup message.

Code :

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, ElementClickInterceptedException
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
import os
import pandas as pd


def get_jobs(keyword, num_jobs, verbose, path, slp_time):
    
    '''Gathers jobs as a dataframe, scraped from Glassdoor'''
    
    #Initializing the webdriver
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    
    #Timeout value for 10 seconds
    options.add_argument('--timeout=15')
    
    #Uncomment the line below if you'd like to scrape without a new Chrome window every time.
    #options.add_argument('headless')
    
    driver_path = path
    options.add_argument(f"webdriver.chrome.driver={driver_path}")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    driver.set_window_size(1120, 1000)
    
    
    #Change the path to where chromedriver is in your home folder.
    #driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path, options=options)
    #driver = selenium.webdriver.chrome.service(executable_path=path, options=options)
    #driver.set_window_size(1120, 1000)
    
    url = "https://www.glassdoor.com/Job/jobs.htm?suggestCount=0&suggestChosen=false&clickSource=searchBtn&typedKeyword="+keyword+"&sc.keyword="+keyword+"&locT=&locId=&jobType="
    
    #url = 'https://www.glassdoor.com/Job/jobs.htm?sc.keyword="' + keyword + '"&locT=C&locId=1147401&locKeyword=San%20Francisco,%20CA&jobType=all&fromAge=-1&minSalary=0&includeNoSalaryJobs=true&radius=100&cityId=-1&minRating=0.0&industryId=-1&sgocId=-1&seniorityType=all&companyId=-1&employerSizes=0&applicationType=0&remoteWorkType=0'
    
    driver.get(url)
    jobs = []

while len(jobs) < num_jobs:  #If true, should be still looking for new jobs.

    #Let the page load. Change this number based on your internet speed.
    #Or, wait until the webpage is loaded, instead of hardcoding it.
    time.sleep(slp_time)

    #Test for the "Sign Up" prompt and get rid of it.
    try:    
        #driver.find_element_by_class_name("JobDetails_jobDetailsContainer__y9P3L").click()
        driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "JobDetails_jobDetailsContainer__y9P3L").click()
    except ElementClickInterceptedException:    
        pass
    
    time.sleep(.1)

    try:
        #driver.find_element_by_css_selector('["button class=CloseButton"]').click() #clicking to the X.
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[alt="Close"]').click()
        #driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "CloseButton").click() 
        print('x out worked')
    except:
        print('x out failed')
        pass

    
    #Going through each job in this page
    #job_buttons = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("JobsList_jobsList_lqjTr")  #jl for Job Listing. These are the buttons we're going to click.
    #job_buttons = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                        #EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "JobsList_jobsList_lqjTr")))
                        
    job_buttons = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "JobsList_jobsList__lqjTr") 
    print('Number of jobs found:', len(job_buttons))
    
    for job_button in job_buttons:  

        print("Progress: {}".format("" + str(len(jobs)) + "/" + str(num_jobs)))
        if len(jobs) >= num_jobs:
            break

        job_button.click()  #You might 
        time.sleep(1)
        collected_successfully = False
        
        while not collected_successfully:
            try:
                company_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="employerName"]').text
                location = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="location"]').text
                job_title = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[contains(@class, "title")]').text
                job_description = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="jobDescriptionContent desc"]').text
                collected_successfully = True
            except:
                time.sleep(5)

        try:
            salary_estimate = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@class="gray salary"]').text
        except NoSuchElementException:
            salary_estimate = -1 #You need to set a "not found value. It's important."
        
        try:
            rating = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@class="rating"]').text
        except NoSuchElementException:
            rating = -1 #You need to set a "not found value. It's important."

        #Printing for debugging
        if verbose:
            print("Job Title: {}".format(job_title))
            print("Salary Estimate: {}".format(salary_estimate))
            print("Job Description: {}".format(job_description[:500]))
            print("Rating: {}".format(rating))
            print("Company Name: {}".format(company_name))
            print("Location: {}".format(location))

        #Going to the Company tab...
        #clicking on this:
        #<div class="tab" data-tab-type="overview"><span>Company</span></div>
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="tab" and @data-tab-type="overview"]').click()

            try:
                #<div class="infoEntity">
                #    <label>Headquarters</label>
                #    <span class="value">San Francisco, CA</span>
                #</div>
                headquarters = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="infoEntity"]//label[text()="Headquarters"]//following-sibling::*').text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                headquarters = -1

            try:
                size = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="infoEntity"]//label[text()="Size"]//following-sibling::*').text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                size = -1

            try:
                founded = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="infoEntity"]//label[text()="Founded"]//following-sibling::*').text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                founded = -1

            try:
                type_of_ownership = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="infoEntity"]//label[text()="Type"]//following-sibling::*').text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                type_of_ownership = -1

            try:
                industry = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="infoEntity"]//label[text()="Industry"]//following-sibling::*').text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                industry = -1

            try:
                sector = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="infoEntity"]//label[text()="Sector"]//following-sibling::*').text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                sector = -1

            try:
                revenue = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="infoEntity"]//label[text()="Revenue"]//following-sibling::*').text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                revenue = -1

            try:
                competitors = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="infoEntity"]//label[text()="Competitors"]//following-sibling::*').text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                competitors = -1

        except NoSuchElementException:  #Rarely, some job postings do not have the "Company" tab.
            headquarters = -1
            size = -1
            founded = -1
            type_of_ownership = -1
            industry = -1
            sector = -1
            revenue = -1
            competitors = -1

            
        if verbose:
            print("Headquarters: {}".format(headquarters))
            print("Size: {}".format(size))
            print("Founded: {}".format(founded))
            print("Type of Ownership: {}".format(type_of_ownership))
            print("Industry: {}".format(industry))
            print("Sector: {}".format(sector))
            print("Revenue: {}".format(revenue))
            print("Competitors: {}".format(competitors))
            print("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@")

        jobs.append({"Job Title" : job_title,
        "Salary Estimate" : salary_estimate,
        "Job Description" : job_description,
        "Rating" : rating,
        "Company Name" : company_name,
        "Location" : location,
        "Headquarters" : headquarters,
        "Size" : size,
        "Founded" : founded,
        "Type of ownership" : type_of_ownership,
        "Industry" : industry,
        "Sector" : sector,
        "Revenue" : revenue,
        "Competitors" : competitors})
        #add job to jobs
        
        
    #Clicking on the "next page" button
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//li[@class="next"]//a').click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("Scraping terminated before reaching target number of jobs. Needed {}, got {}.".format(num_jobs, len(jobs)))
        break

return pd.DataFrame(jobs)  #This line converts the dictionary object into a pandas DataFrame.
```

I have tried using "driver.find_element(by.CLASS_NAME,"....") and also used "driver.find_element(by.CSS_SELECTOR,"...."). But couldn't solve the problem.

Comment: To find the correct tag i recommend to use playwright.
playwright has a auto generate code mechanism to help find tags and ..

you need to install playwright. just search in google and then in your terminal type
**playwright codegen**

Comment: @  r3a9670
Thank You! I will figure out how to use playwright codegen for web scraping.